# Javascript Date.UTC() vs moment.utc()

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for replacing moment js functionality with plain Javascript - the project I need to re-work is not going to have moment.js available going forward. I have not worked with javascript Date in a while, so needs some good eyes on this. My question is two-fold.

**Part 1: what I get with Date.UTC() is not the same as the value I get with moment.utc()**

```
//original value: Mon Mar 04 2019 05:21:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
var m = moment(date);
m.utc();
return m.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[Z]');
//m.format: 2019-03-04T13:21:00Z
```

This is my replacement for m.utc (it designers improvement):

```
var d = new Date(date);
var utcVal = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds(), d.getMilliseconds());
var d2 = new Date(utcVal);
var sec = d2.getSeconds()<10? "0"+d2.getSeconds():d2.getSeconds();
var mm = d2.getMonth()<10? "0"+(d2.getMonth()+1):d2.getMonth();
var formated = d2.getFullYear()+"-"+mm+"-"+d2.getDate()+"T"+d2.getHours()+":"+d2.getMinutes()+":"+sec+"Z";

 //d2 formated: 2019-03-3T21:21:00Z
```

I'd like to have something much cleaner than what I have above. Most glaring problem is that both the date and the hours are wrong. How can I fix this without usage of any other external libraries?

**Part 2: I would like to confirm if what I already have for moment replacement is the right thing:**

```
//value: 2019-03-04T13:21:00Z
var m = moment.utc(value);
m.local();
return m.toDate();
```

Here is my replacement for the above (it seems the .utc conversion is not used, .local is used instead):

```
 var d = new Date(value);
 return new Date(d.toLocaleString());
```

The above appears to be doing the right thing, but I wonder if there are edge cases I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

For Part 1, you should look into the `toISOString()` method. Attach that to the Date object and it will return a string in the format you're looking for with a lot less work.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I could be misunderstanding, but seems as though `toISOString` would satisfy the requirement here:

```js
var event = new Date('Mon Mar 04 2019 05:21:00 GMT-0800');
console.log(event.toString());
console.log(event.toISOString());
```

Comment: Wow, yes, toISOString() looks like the thing! Thank you!